# Insert a routing parameter before {controller}

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a working API with a bunch of controllers, with a single database specified in config file.
Now I want to make the the API multi database and make the target database a part of the url.

I use attributes on controllers now and default routing.

Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMVC();
```

FolderController.cs:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FoldersController : ControllerBase { ...
```

and action on controller:

```
[HttpGet("{Parent:Guid}", Name = "Get")]
public IActionResult Get(Guid Parent) {...
```

So what that gives me is the standard overall template that looks like this:

```
https://api.example.com/api/{controller}/{action}
```

What I'd want is to make the database a part of the url, the intuitive place being in front of the controller. I can also skip the second `api` bit as I'm not running anything else on that base address.

```
https://api.example.com/{database}/{controller}/{action}
```

I've been able to extract the database name by changing the controller attribute to:

```
[Route("{database}/[controller]")]
```

But then I'd have to insert code in every action method to check for route etc, with the risk of not implementing it consitently (beside the extra typing).

Ideally I'd like to add this to the default route in `startup.cs`, and add a service to the middleware that would check the privileges for the authenticated user on the requested database and continue as appropriate. That way I'd have my security in one place and no way to forget it in a controller.

I havent been able to figure out how to mix that with the attributes, they seem to conflict with each other.

Can this be done? Does anyone have some pointers for me get out of this?

Comment: I could not find the regular MVC equivalent, but for razor pages, I've used `IPageRouteModelConvention` to add the `{database}` part of the route. Then picking it up in middleware by utilizing `HttpContext.GetRouteData()'.

Answer (score 0):

By understand I know we can do it. You need to implement IHttpHandler.
You can refer to the following example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dynamic-and-friendly-url-using-mvc/